# Mvvmcross Touch How to create custom controls list dynamically in UIViewController

Tags: data-binding, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

There is a custom Button list in the MyViewModel.

```
public class MyViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    ...
    public List<CustomButton> MyButtons;
}
```

In the Android project, these were added and binded by axml.

```
<Mvx.MvxLinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource MyButtons"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/item_custom_button" />
```

In the iOS project, I want to place these buttons horizontally on top of the screen and bind them to MyButtons.
But I am not sure how can create these buttons dynamically and bind them.
Any advice?

Comment: I believe there is a question where this has already been asked/answered (but I can't see it right now...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a built-in control for iOS similar to `MvxLinearLayout`.

This is mainly because iOS has traditionally used pixel perfect layout rather than `StackPanel` like effects.

You can implement this yourself by binding a View Property to `MyButtons` and then implementing the logic within that property to remove and add the child controls yourself (the layout will be a key part of this - constraints may help here). The `MvxView` class may help you here.

Some examples that may particularly help are:

- N=32 - shows `MvxView` in action - see http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/n32-truth-about-viewmodels-starring.html
- Fluent Layout - http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/playing-with-constraints.html